# Point homepage to custom php page

Tags: customization

I've installed a store theme and my client asked me to use a different `homepage` before the current default homepage he wants to name `site.com/store`.
So I've renamed the original `index.php` to `store.php` and created another `index.php`.

How can I do now to create a link to `store.php` from `index.php`?

the contents of `store.php` cannot be posted in a static page because it's full of php code for last products etc.

Does exist some way to point it?

Answer (score 2):

Please familiarize yourself with the WordPress templating system, beginning with the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

In the WordPress template system, a specific template file, **`front-page.php`**, is used for a customized site front page. (Note also the nomenclature; in WordPress parlance, the *home* page refers to the **Blog Posts Index**, and *not* to the Site Front Page.)

So, you simply need to create `front-page.php`, and include in it whatever front-page content you want to display.

Comment: thanks you for the info now I have created a working `front-page.php`, It's not clear to me how to add the `store` page now, I have the `front-page` which can link to articles, but how can I create a working store page? I've tried `home.php` and `index.php` but I get a `404` not-found page.

Comment: WordPress does not recognize a template file named `store.php`. You need to put that content **in `front-page.php`**.